# Trigger richtextbox textchanged event until it detects certain text

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, textchanged

I am working on serialport that can send and received certain commands. I would like to implement a retry feature which will allow me (the client) to resend data until the device (server) received and send a response to me.

Because of that I created a simple code that can illustrate this kind of function.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Sample")
    End Sub

    Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
       Console.WriteLine("Trigger textchanged")

       Dim totalLines As Integer = Me.RichTextBox1.Lines.Length
       Dim lastLine As String = Me.RichTextBox1.Lines(totalLines - 1)

       Dim CSTAT_Check As Boolean = lastLine Like "*Sample*"
       If CSTAT_Check = True Then
           RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Sample")
       End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The way it works is like this, I will clicked the button to append a `sample` string to `richtextbox` then the `richtextbox` `textchange_event` will be triggered causing it to resend the `sample` string to **itself** and will causes it to `trigger` another `textchange_event` and so on and so forth until the device received the `sample` string which in return the device (server) will send a `sample_accepted` string to my device (client) and because the `textchanged_event` doesnt detect the `sample` string in the last line of richtextbox it will no longer send another `sample` string to `richtextbox`.

It's little hard to understand so I will create a simple diagram

**Client (Me)**                                                   **Server (Device)**

Send `sample` string                          `Doesn't detected`

Send `sample` string **`again`**        `Doesn't detected` **`again`**

Send `sample` string **`again`**        `Doesn't detected` **`again`**

Send `sample` string **`again`**        `Doesn't detected` **`again`**

Send `sample` string **`again`**        **`Detected`** `sample` will **`send`** **`sample_accepted`**

Client Will **`no longer`** send `sample` string because the server detected it already.

**The problem in my code is** it seems like it doesn't trigger the `textchanged_event` again after its first trigger.

Comment: Could you please post the interface for the actual serial port calls you are making? Also the code to you're using to call the serial port? This rich text box example is getting in the way of you getting a good answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity, sure. I'll try to recreate it in a simplest form.

Answer (score 0):

???*If you change a property inside the code that responds to that property being changed, another changed event will not fire.*??? You need to manually trigger the textchanged event after you make the changes.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Sample")
    End Sub

    Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
       Console.WriteLine("Trigger textchanged")

       Dim totalLines As Integer = Me.RichTextBox1.Lines.Length
       Dim lastLine As String = Me.RichTextBox1.Lines(totalLines - 1)

       Dim CSTAT_Check As Boolean = lastLine Like "*Sample*"
       If CSTAT_Check = True Then
           RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Sample")
           RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender, New EventArgs())
       End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: An error appears after adding your 2 lines of code. **1.** `Error 2 'Public Event TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.` then **2.** `Error 1 'Handled' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'.`

Comment: Sorry, c# dev here. I forget sometimes that not everything maps exactly between different .Net languages despite similarities. I've edited.

Comment: @CaryBondoc PS -- I do fear that this will just cause an infinite loop. I'm not sure that this is a good fit for handling client-server retries.

Comment: this seems to be good. I'll try to apply it to my system. Thanks for your warning. :)

Comment: Sure, thanks a lot. I ended up using another way. :)

Comment: This is crazy. It's doing a **double recursion**. Not only is it calling `RichTextBox1_TextChanged` recursively, but because it is changing the text in `RichTextBox1` then it'll cause the handler to be called too.

Comment: @Enigmativity Actually its not double recursion. I just ran the code myself to double check. When the text is changed within the TextChanged event handler, the TextChanged event does **not** fire again (at least not for the AppendText method used here).

Comment: @weirdev - That's interesting. I just tested it myself. It seems that the `TextChanged` isn't fired from `AppendText` or even setting `Text`.

Comment: @weirdev, actually I've also tested it and Enigmativity seems right. Sometimes there are double recursion.

Comment: @CaryBondoc This seems strange. It should either experience double recursion every time or not at all.